# How to re-run useEffect after a submit function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

> Hello Guys!
> So in my Project, I do a fetch data function in useeffect but when I add a new element to the firestore I want that the useEffect to run again so in the list will contain the added element, somebody can give me advice on how can I do it ?

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (session) {
      fetchTodos();
    }
  }, [session]);

  const fetchTodos = async () => {
    const fetchedtodos = [];

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, session.user.uid));

    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      return fetchedtodos.push({ id: doc.id, data: doc.data() });
    });

    setTodos(fetchedtodos);
  };

const submitHandler = async (todo) => {
    
    const data = await addDoc(collection(db, session.user.uid), {
      todo,
      createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
      type: "active",
    });

    
  }
```

> I want that when I run the submitHandler the useeffect run again so the list will  be the newest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get a `useEffect` hook to run again, is to change something in the dependency array, or to not provide an array at all, and get the component to re-render (by changing props or state). See [useEffect Documentation](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useEffect#parameters)

You could just call `fetchTodos` directly after you call `addDoc`:

```
const submitHandler = async (todo) => {
    
  const data = await addDoc(collection(db, session.user.uid), {
    todo,
    createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
    type: "active",
  });

  return fetchTodos();
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the best way to do what you are trying to do is to have any requests that modify your data in the backend return the difference and then modify your state accordingly:

```
const submitHandler = async (todo) => {
    const data = await addDoc(collection(db, session.user.uid), {
        todo,
        createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
        type: 'active',
    });

    setTodos((prev) => [...prev, data]);
};
```

This way you don't have to do any large requests for what is mostly the same data within the same session.

Of course, this method is not ideal if multiple clients/users can modify your backend's data, or if you do not control what the endpoint responds with.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello mate!
Thank You for help ,in the first try i tried this method but the new data in the state will be a firebase request that cause problems so that's why i wanted to trigger the useEffect again